# Why do I receive deprecated package warnings when using npm install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I hope you are doing well!

I got asked about why should I use `-f` to force `npm install` packages to install. In the documentation it states that

> force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk.
> But does this mean that it redownloads global packages for the local project or what does it solve exactly?

Another thing happens is when I use `npm install`, I see a lot of warnings in the console that

> WARNING: X package is deprecated
> But when I run `npm outdated` I see that all packages are all fairly up to date (all match the recommended version to download), so I assume this might be a dependency for a certain package. But does it affect our work negatively? Why does this happen?

For the packages I download, I generally look for packages that have in the 6 digits Weekly Downloads from npm so I don't think we are using unfamiliar packages.

I am asking these questions because they have been asked to me but I don't have a straight answer to them.

Thank You!

I don't understand how `npm install -f` works